# Is there a SQL Server collation option that will allow matching different apostrophes?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation

I'm currently using SQL Server 2016 with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI collation.  As expected, queries with the letter e will match values with the letters e, è, é, ê, ë, etc because of the accent insensitive option of the collation.  However, queries with a ' (U+0027) do not match values containing a ’ (U+2019). I would like to know if such a collation exists where this case would match, since it's easier to type ' than it is to know that ’ is keystroke Alt-0146.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confident in saying no. The main thing, here, is that the two characters are different (although similar). With accents, e and ê are still both an e (just one has an accent). This enables you (for example) to do searches for things like `SELECT * FROM Games WHERE [Name] LIKE 'Pokémon%';` and still have rows containing `Pokemon` return (because people haven't used the accent).

The best thing I could suggest would be to use `REPLACE` (at least in your `WHERE` clause) so that both rows are returned. That is, however, likely going to get expensive.

If you know what columns are going to be a problem you could add a Computed Column to that table and index it appropriately. Then you could use that column in your `WHERE` clause, but display the original one. Something like:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
--Create dbo.Sample table and data
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample (String varchar(500));

INSERT INTO dbo.Sample
VALUES ('This is a string that does not contain either apostrophe'),
       ('Where as this string, isn''t without at least one'),
       ('’I have one of them as well’'),
       ('’Well, I''m going to use both’');
GO
--First attempt (without the column)
SELECT String
FROM dbo.Sample
WHERE String LIKE '%''%'; --Only returns 2 of the rows
GO
--Create a PERSISTED Column
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sample ADD StringRplc AS REPLACE(String,'’','''');
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_Sample_StringRplc ON dbo.Sample (StringRplc) INCLUDE (String);
GO
--Second attempt
SELECT String
FROM dbo.Sample
WHERE StringRplc LIKE '%''%'; --Returns 3 rows
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.Sample;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct. There is no such collation. You can easily verify this with the below.

```
DECLARE @dynSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT * FROM ('  + 
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + name + ''' AS name, IIF( NCHAR(0x0027) = NCHAR(0x2019) COLLATE ' + name + ', 1,0) AS Equal'
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
FOR XML PATH('')
), 12, 0+ 0x7fffffff)
)
 + ') t 
 ORDER BY Equal, name';

PRINT @dynSql;

EXEC (@dynSql);
```